# Is $C_c^\infty$ dense in $W^{1,p}\cap C_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set. I was wondering if $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C_0(\Omega)$ with $1\leq p<\infty$.

Here $C_0(\Omega)$ is the space of functions of $C(\overline{\Omega})$ which are zero on $\partial\Omega$, and the space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C_0(\Omega)$ is endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}}+\|\cdot\|_{L^\infty}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a function $f$ and convolve with a Mollifier $\phi_{\epsilon}$ and convert it into compactly supported smooth function $(1_{B_r(0)} \times f) * \phi_{\epsilon}$ where $1_{B_r(0)}$ is an indicator function of compact set $Closure(B_r(0))$. It is known that $$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} (1_{B_r(0)} \times f)  * \phi_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f.$$
Since $\Omega$ is a bounded set, we dont have to worry about compactness since $f|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$.
We now prove that closure of $C^{\infty}(\Omega + B_{\epsilon}(0))$ (when functions are restricted to $\Omega$) contains $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \cap C_0(\Omega)$.
Hence enough to prove: $$f  * \phi_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$$
Let $f \in C_0(\Omega)$,
$$f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x) = \int (f(x-y)-f(x)) \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy $$
$$|f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)| \leq \int |f(x-y)-f(x)| \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy $$
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous as $\Omega$ is a bounded set and $f|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ and since $\phi_{\epsilon}$ is supported in the set $B_{\epsilon}(0)$, we have by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small:
$$|f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon_f \int  \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy $$
$$|f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon_f$$
Hence $f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ uniformly.

By uniform convergence, we also have that,
$$\int |f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)|^p dx \leq \epsilon_f^p \times \mu(\Omega)$$
Hence $f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ in $L_p$.

Now observe that:
$$f'_{\epsilon}(x) = \int f'(x-y) \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy $$ and we repeat the same proof as above to conclude that $f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ in $||.||_{W^{1,p}} + ||.||_{L_{\infty}}$. To repeat the proof, we might need the condition $f'$ is continuous and $f'|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ OR $f'$ is uniformly continuous. Try this out and let me know.

Hence any $f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ for any $f \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) \cap C_0(\Omega)$

You can also find some materials in:
http://wwwarchive.math.psu.edu/anovikov/acm105/mollifiers.pdf

EDIT:
The idea is to work with $\Omega'$ where $\Omega'$ is slightly larger than $\Omega$ such that $Closure(\Omega) \subset M \subset \Omega'$ where $M$ is a compact set. Extend the $L_p$ function $f'$ to $\Omega'$. we need to set $f'(x) = 0$, $\forall x \in \Omega' \setminus \Omega$.
Using density of $C(\Omega')$ in $L^p(\Omega')$, one can approximate $f'$ by a continuous function $g$ on $\Omega'$ and approximate the continuous function $g$ by smooth function $g_{\epsilon}$ on $Closure(\Omega)$ by using uniform continuity of $g$ on $M$ and use the inequality $|f'_{\epsilon}-g_{\epsilon}|_{L_p(\Omega)} \leq |f'-g|_{L_p(M)}$ and show that $f'_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f'$ on $\Omega$ by triangle inequality.
Thus completing the proof by observing $|f'-g|_{L_p(\Omega)} \leq |f'-g|_{L_p(M)} \leq |f'-g|_{L_p(\Omega')}$. 
The following link has some of the above details. See Theorem 1.28,Page 18,19, in [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf)

EDIT: In the above we have proved that closure of $C^{\infty}( \Omega + B_{\epsilon}(0))$ (when functions are restricted to $\Omega$) contains $W^{1,p} \cap C_0(\Omega)$. Please see below for the argument that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (smooth function on compact set) is dense.

Its enough to prove $(f 1_K) * \phi_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f * \phi_{\epsilon}$ i.e., $(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K}) * \phi_{\epsilon} \rightarrow 0$. Now $$|(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K}) * \phi_{\epsilon}| = |\int (f 1_{\Omega \setminus K})(x-y) * \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy|  \leq \int |(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K})(x-y)| * \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy.$$
Since $f|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded set, by uniform continuity of $f$, there exists $K = K_{\gamma, \epsilon} \subset \Omega$, $K_{\gamma, \epsilon}$ compact such that $|f(x)| \leq \gamma \epsilon^{n+1}$, $\forall x \in \Omega \setminus K_{\gamma, \epsilon}$. Note that $|\phi_{\epsilon}(y)| \leq 1/\epsilon^n$ (see pdf in the link above). Using this, we get:
$$|(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K}) * \phi_{\epsilon} (x)|\leq \int |(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K})(x-y)| * \phi_{\epsilon}(y) dy \leq \gamma \epsilon \mu(\Omega).$$ To prove derivative, converges use exactly same argument with $\phi'_{\epsilon}$ in place of $\phi_{\epsilon}$ and use $|\phi'_{\epsilon}(y)| \leq 1/\epsilon^{n+1}$.

EDIT:
As @rubik pointed out in the comments the proof is correct/complete when we have $$\mu(\Omega \setminus K_{\frac{3}{2} \times d_{\gamma}})^{1/p} \leq constant \times d_{\gamma}.$$
as $d_{\gamma} \rightarrow 0$, where we can define: $K_{d} = \{x: x \in \Omega, dist(x,\partial \Omega) \geq d\}$ and set $K_{\gamma,\epsilon} = K_{d_{\gamma}}$ for $d_{\gamma}$ which depends on continuity of $f$ at the boundary. This is true atleast for open balls/rectangles of any radius $r$  in any $N$ dimensional space when $p=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas and materials. It is true that the function $f_\epsilon=f*\phi_\epsilon$ with $\phi_\epsilon$ the standard mollifier satisfies $f_\epsilon\to f$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C_0(\Omega)$. However, $f_\epsilon\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$, not in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. In this way, it seems that one needs to think about how to approximate $C^\infty$ by $C_c^\infty$ in the $W^{1.p}$ sense (the problem mainly lies in the approximation of the gradient).

Comment: If this could be done, we would be able to choose a $\zeta\in C_c^\infty$ such that $f\zeta$ is close to $f$ in $W^{1,p}\cap C_0$. Since $f\zeta$ is compactly supported, we then could consider the convolution $(f\zeta)*\phi_\epsilon$ which is in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and close to $f\zeta$ in $W^{1,p}\cap C_0$ if $\epsilon$ is small enough. In my opinion, this is not obvious... By the way, a similar question is whether $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $W_0^{1,p}\cap L^q$.

Comment: We can do: $(1_{K} f_{\epsilon}) = (1_K f)* \phi$. We need to show $(1_{K} f_{\epsilon}) = (1_K f)* \phi \rightarrow f_{\epsilon} = f*\phi$. Now use Youngs inequality to prove this i.e.,: $|| (1_K f)* \phi - f*\phi ||_{L_p} = || ((1_K f)-f) * \phi ||_{L_p} \leq ||((1_K f)-f)||_{L_p} \times ||\phi||_{L_1} $. Since $\phi$ is integrable then we are done w.r.t convergence in $L_p$. For derivative, we need to replace $\phi$ with $\phi'$ and need $\phi'$ to be integrable. Need to think.

Comment: I got an idea, try to prove $f (1_K * \phi_{\epsilon}) \rightarrow f$ and $f' (1_K * \phi_{\epsilon}) + f (1_K * \phi_{\epsilon})' \rightarrow f'$ since $f,f' \in C_{\infty}$ and $f (1_K * \phi_{\epsilon}) \in C_{c,\infty}$. Basically convolve the mollifier with indicator function rather than the whole product.This might work.

Comment: It seems that there is always the issue of controlling $\nabla\phi_\epsilon$ in using the truncation and then the convolution to approximate a function in $W^{1,p}$...

Comment: Its enough to prove $(f 1_{K}) * \phi'_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f * \phi'_{\epsilon} $. Hence $(f 1_{\Omega \setminus K}) * \phi'_{\epsilon} \rightarrow 0 $. Now use the fact that $|f(x)| \leq \epsilon^2$ for $x \in \Omega \setminus K$ for $K$ large enough due to uniform continuity of $f$ and $\mu(B_{\epsilon}) = O(\epsilon^n)$ and $|\phi_{\epsilon}'(x)| \leq 1/\epsilon^{n+1}$.

Comment: See the link to pdfs i sent for $|\phi_{\epsilon} (x)| \leq 1/\epsilon^{n}$ and this implies $|\phi'_{\epsilon} (x)| \leq 1/\epsilon^{n+1}$. This is because we have a fixed mollifier $\eta(x)$ and we get $\phi_{\epsilon}(x) = 1/\epsilon^n \eta(x/\epsilon)$

Comment: I updated the answer check it out and let me know.

Comment: Edited the proof / answer to the best i can. Check if it helps. Let me know if you are still not convinced. Lets see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Given $\epsilon>0$, if $K$ satisfies $f(x)\le\epsilon^{n+1}$ in $\Omega\setminus K$, then in order to make $f1_K*\phi_\epsilon\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ we need to ask $\epsilon<\text{dist}(\partial\Omega,K)$, which is, however, not necessarily true.

Comment: More precisely, for any $x_0\in\partial\Omega$, there is $\delta(\epsilon)$ s.t. if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)|\le\epsilon^{n+1}$. So $\text{dist}(\partial\Omega,K)\le \delta$. But we don't know if $\epsilon<\delta(\epsilon)$ unless the modulus of the continuity of $f$ is prescribed. Nevertheless, by fixing slightly your answer the fact that $f1_K*\phi_\epsilon\to f*\phi_\epsilon$ still holds. See below.

Comment: Set $f^\delta:=f*\phi_{\delta}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $K_\epsilon\subset\subset\Omega$ be such that $|f|<\epsilon$ in $\Omega\setminus K_\epsilon$. Consider $f_{K}:=f1_{K}$ with $K:=K_\epsilon+B_\delta\subset\subset\Omega$ and
$f_K^\delta:=f_K*\phi_{\delta}\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, provided $\delta<\frac12\text{dist}(\partial\Omega,K_\epsilon)$. So $|f^\delta(x)-f_K^\delta(x)|=\int_{B_\delta(x)}|f_{\Omega\setminus K}(y)|\phi_\delta(x-y)\,dy\le\epsilon$. However, the same argument would become subtle for $Df_K^\delta-Df^\delta$. See below.

Comment: Since $Df^\delta-Df_K^\delta=\int_{B_\delta(x)}f_{\Omega\setminus K}(y)D\phi_\delta(x-y)dy$, $|Df^\delta(x)-Df_K^\delta(x)|\le C\epsilon/\delta$ and $Df^\delta-Df_K^\delta=0$ for $x\in K_\epsilon$. Hence, $\|Df_K^\delta-Df^\delta\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\le C\frac{\epsilon|\Omega\setminus K_\epsilon|^{1/p}}{\delta}$. So we need to expect that $\frac{|\Omega\setminus K_\epsilon|^{1/p}}{\delta}\le C$ with $C$ independent of $\epsilon$. This leads to $|\Omega\setminus K_\epsilon|^{1/p}\le C\delta\le C\frac12\text{dist}(\partial\Omega,K_\epsilon)$, which is subtle to be verified.

Comment: I think there is a small error in your derivation since $Df^{\delta}-Df_K^{\delta} = 0$, for $K_{\epsilon+\delta}$, defining $K_d = \{x: x \in \Omega, dist(x,\partial \Omega) \geq d\}$. So the final criteria is: $\mu(\Omega \setminus K_{\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}dist(\Omega,K_{\epsilon})})^{1/p} \leq C \frac{1}{2}  dist(\Omega,K_{\epsilon})$

Comment: Inshort, we need $\mu(\Omega \setminus K_{\frac{3}{2} d})^{1/p} \leq contant \times d$. edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: This seems true for open balls/rectangles of radius< 1, for any $N$, for $p=1$ as $d \rightarrow 0$. So i think what you want is true for $p=1$ for these specific domains (Balls/rectangles of radius <1).

Comment: One further idea could be that if we assume $f$ to be close to constant in $B_{\delta}(x)$ then $Df^{\delta}-Df^{\delta}_K \approx constant \times \int_{B_{\delta}(x)} D\phi_{\delta}(x-y)$. We can try applying some highdimensional equivalent of fundamental theorem of calculus (may be divergence theorem) to conclude $\int_{B_{\delta}(x)} D\phi_{\delta}(x-y) \leq sup_{y \in \partial B_{\delta}(0)} |\phi_{\delta}(y)| = 0$. If $f$ is not constant in the Ball of radius $\delta$ then we have to do an approximation. Try this out.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Indeed, it seems to be "yes" for balls or rectangles. Focusing on the ratio $|\Omega-K|^{1/p}/d$ appeared in our derivation, it seems to be possibly bounded only if $p=1$. Actually, take $K=\{x\in\Omega:d(x)>\epsilon\}$ where $d(x)=dist(x,\partial\Omega)$. By the coarea formula,
$|\Omega-K|=\int_0^\epsilon\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(d^{-1}(t))$. By the isoperimetric ineq, $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(d^{-1}(t))\ge C(n)|\{x\in\Omega:d(x)>t\}|^{(N-1)/N}\ge C(|K|,n)$ for a.e. t; So $|\Omega-K|^{1/p}/\epsilon\ge C(n,|K|)\epsilon^{1/p-1}$, which is possibly bounded only if $p=1$.

Comment: By the way, I'd like to mention that the mollification process $f*\phi_\epsilon\to f$ in $W^{1,p}$ seems not necessarily valid for any $\Omega$. Since during the process, we regarded $f$ as 0 outside $\Omega$. This extension can't guarantee $Df$ is still in $L^p$. So, generally, that approximation of the gradient works locally. You can check a relevant book to see how to construct a global approximation (partition of unity would be used, see the result that "$C^\infty$ is dense in $W^{1,p}$").

Comment: You are correct we do need $Df(x)$ to exist for $x \in  \partial \Omega$ and $Df(x) \in L_p(\Omega')$  for  extended $f$ (extended with 0 value)

Comment: Anyway, the above process works if we know the trivial extension is valid for $Df$, like when $f\in W_0^{1,p}$. This can be guaranteed by assuming $\Omega$ to be Lipschitz, for which the trace characterization tells that $W^{1,p}\cap C_0\subset W_0^{1,p}$. In addition, if $p>N$ then it holds the Sobolev embedding $W_0^{1,p}\hookrightarrow C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$. Clearly, this fact could affirmatively answer the question. As for arbitrary $\Omega$, the corresponding conclusions remain to explore. Let's expect to see that soon.